# How to select specific viewports with media queries

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries

I am trying to select an area between **767px, and 1024px**.

I want this to apply to the **screen**, iPad **portrait**, but **NOT** iPad ***landscape***.

These are some queries that I have tried with no success.

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1024px) { ... }`

Problem lies with the iPad landscape falls within the query of 767 and 1024, so I don't know how to exclude the iPad landscape specific viewport.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css" />
```

so then do this:
so <style @media screen (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){ /** portrait **/ } @media screen (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){ /** landscape **/ } </style>

i'm not sure what you mean...those do that. either way, here's another solution so you can exclude iPad Landscape  /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

Comment: I'm wanting it to be all within the same stylesheet

Comment: so &#60;style @media screen (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){ }

Comment: max device width only works for devices.  I'm looking for screen, as well as ipad portrait.